# R programming: selecting rows based on their numeric value in different columns

Tags: r

I looked for similar problems but couldn't find an answer for selecting rows based on their numeric value in different columns. I have a dataset looking like this (in total including 24 studies/columns and over 28.000 rows)

```
    header <- c("symbol", "gene1", "gene2", "gene3")
    study1 <- c("0.06", "0.01", "NA", "NA")
    study2 <- c("0.09", "NA", "0.02", "0.08", "0.07")
    study3 <- c("0.09", "NA", "NA", "0.1")
    DF<- data.frame(header, study1, study2, study3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    DF

    ID study1 study2 study3
    1 gene1   0.06   0.09   0.09
    2 gene2   0.01     NA     NA
    3 gene3     NA   0.02     NA
    4 gene4     NA   0.07    0.1
```

>

I want to make a new data.frame that includes all columns BUT only the rows which have a value <= 0.05 for at least one study (i.e. one column). NA can be considered as > 0.05

Because I am a beginner in R programming, I started simple with writing code filtering only for one column and that works fine by applying "which"

```
    new_DF<-DF[which(as.numeric(DF$study1)<=0.05),]
```

Until here I was very happy for myself :-), however, how do I adapt this for the multiple columns? I tried including a wildcard "*"

```
    new_DF<-DF[which(as.numeric(DF$study*)<=0.05),]
```

BUT I get an error stating "Error: unexpected ')' in "new_DF<-DF[which(as.numeric(DF$study*)". I also tried different things using the dplyd package, subset or grep function, but always get similar error-messages.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could subset the rows with at least one value that is less than or equal to 0.05 by using `rowSums`.  Convert the dataset to a logical matrix (`DF[-1] <= 0.05` - the `-1` is to remove the first column which is non-numeric).  The output of the above will have `TRUE/FALSE/NA`.  When we do the `rowSums` with `na.rm=TRUE`, we get the count of the number of elements in each row that are less than or equal to 0.05.  For rows 1 and 4, there are no elements that satisfy the condition, so the sum will be 0 and for others it is not 0.  When we negate (`!`) the 0 will be converted to TRUE and all others FALSE.  But, we need to remove the rows with 0, so negate again to change the TRUE to FALSE and viceversa.  Then, we subset using this logical vector index.

```
 DF[!!rowSums(DF[-1] <= 0.05, na.rm=TRUE),]
 #     ID study1 study2 study3
 #2 gene2   0.01     NA     NA
 #3 gene3     NA   0.02     NA
```

Comment: Sorry previous comment was mistake :-)

my expected output is a subset of rows, so the first option.
I am afraid, however, that I will loose rows that have <= 0.05 in 1 column, but > 0.05 in other, no?

I do not fully understand the code you have written, thought
- what does the "!!" stand for? "!" is inversed/negative I thought, so this would be double negative? Or does this mean you take the sum of all row, but consider each value by itself?
- the [-1] means you do not consider the selection for the first column (because it is the ID)?

Comment: @khardies I added some explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much, know I try to apply this to similar issues :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is that you have large number of studies, right? You could do it like this, but there might be a better way:

```
header <- c("symbol", "gene1", "gene2", "gene3")
study1 <- c("0.06", "0.01", "NA", "NA")
study2 <- c("0.09", "NA", "0.02", "0.08")
study3 <- c("0.09", "NA", "NA", "0.1")
DF<- data.frame(header, study1, study2, study3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


nrstudies <-3 #change the number of studies to fit your study
text <- ""
formtext <-"(DF$studyNR <= 0.05)"

for(i in 1:nrstudies){
  newtext<-gsub("NR",i,formtext) # substitutes the Substring "NR" for i 

 if(i!=1){
          text<- paste(text, newtext, sep="|")
 }else{
          text <- newtext
 }
}

DF <- DF[eval(parse(text=text)),]
```

Comment: Parse is like for-loops in R: most of the time, they're not the answer.